# Java and Python socket working localhost but not working on any other IP

Tags: java, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

This is client code in **Java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Socket rpiSocket = null; 
        DataInputStream in = null;
        PrintStream out = null;
        String str="Akif";

        try {
            rpiSocket = new Socket("localhost",5560); 
            out = new PrintStream(rpiSocket.getOutputStream());
            in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(rpiSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
        }

        try {
        if (rpiSocket != null && out != null && in != null) {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Please input your command ");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                String command = scanner.nextLine();

                if(command.equals("KILL")) {
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("Sending command to client: " + command);
                out.print(command);

                 byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                in.read(bytes);
                String reply = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println("Reply from server: " + reply.trim());
            }
        }

            rpiSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Connections closed successfully");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
        }
    }
```

This is server code in **Python**

```
import socket
from sys import getsizeof

host = ''
#host = '192.168.2.181'
port = 5560

storedValue = "Yo, what's up?"

def setupServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Socket created.")
    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
    print("Socket bind comPlete.")
    return s

def setupConnection():
    s.listen(1) # Allows one connection at a time.
    print("Waiting for client")
    conn, address = s.accept()
    return conn

def GET():
    reply = storedValue
    return reply

def REPEAT(dataMessage):
    reply = dataMessage[1]
    return reply

def dataTransfer(conn, s):
    # A big loop that sends/receives data until told not to.
    while True:
        # Receive the data
        data = conn.recv(1028) # receive the data
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        data = data.strip()
        print("data value from client: " + data)
        # Split the data such that you separate the command
        # from the rest of the data.
        command = str(data)
        print("data length from client: " + command)
        reply = ""
        if command == "GET":
            reply = GET()
            print (command)
            print (reply)
        elif command == 'REPEAT':
            reply = REPEAT('akif')
        elif command == 'EXIT':
            print("Our client has left us :(")
            break
        elif command == 'KILL':
            print("Our server is shutting down.")
            s.close()
            break
        else:
            reply = 'Unknown Command'
        # Send the reply back to the client
        conn.sendall(bytes(reply, 'utf-8'))
        print("Data has been sent!")
    conn.close()

s = setupServer()

while True:
    try:
        conn = setupConnection()
        dataTransfer(conn, s)
    except:
        break
```

Server and client working perfectly on localhost on my computer(win 10 pro). But if i run client on Win 10 PC and run server on Rpi PC, server working perfectly but client working until this line "in.read(bytes);" and it staying here.

> P.S. = I tried turn of Windows firewall and Windows Defender. I used
>   wifi connection and I tried turned of modem firewall

What can i do to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you got `5560` port opened on the raspberry pi server?

Comment: Yes. raspi can take data from client and then send a reply according the data. But client(java) can't receive the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem is Python version that i used. The problem occur pyton2 versions, but on python3 versions it Works correctly.